# How to process JSON output from WCF in View( MVC3)

Tags: wcf, asp.net-mvc-3, model-view-controller

I have a scenario where the WCF returns the follwing data ( in the function given below) to a VIEW.

```
private List<KeyDatesCalendar> GetKeyDatesCalendarData()
    {
        //Dummy Data for BrandsCalendar CheckList
        var keyDatesCalendar = new List<KeyDatesCalendar>()
        {     

            new KeyDatesCalendar()
            { 
                EventText = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.", 
                EventDate = new DateTime(2011, 02, 09), 
                EventType = 3
            },

            new KeyDatesCalendar()
            { 
                EventText = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.", 
                EventDate = new DateTime(2011, 03, 05), 
                EventType = 3
            },

            new KeyDatesCalendar()
            { 
                EventText = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.", 
                EventDate = new DateTime(2011, 03, 06), 
                EventType = 4
            },
```

};

The processing of the data in view is done by the following code:

```
initCalendars({
    from       : '02/01/2011',
    to         : '01/31/2013',
    dates : [
        @for(int i=0, l=@Model.KeyDatesCalendar.Count; i<l; i++)
        {
            @Html.Raw("['" + @Model.KeyDatesCalendar[i].EventDate.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd") + "'," + @Model.KeyDatesCalendar[i].EventType + ",'" + @Model.KeyDatesCalendar[i].EventText + "']" + (i < (l-1) ? "," : ""));
        }
    ]
});
```

Instead of the hardcoded values in WCF method, how Do i recieve a JSON output and process the same in View.

I am a beginner here, appreciate your detail answers.

Thanks,
Adarsh

Comment: JSON is usually meant to be used by javascript. Your view is using WCF response on server side to render html. So just wondering why you want to use JSON? in your scenario WCF returning `List<KeyDatesCalendar>` makes more sense than JSON string.

Comment: Hi James,The possible reason is the data we will recieve(EventText,EventDate,EventType) is in the form of an XML(from an external system, So i was informed to process it in JSON and render it in View, This is just a sample and hence was hardcoded in WCF method.Let me know if you need any more info.

Comment: Then, it's better to parse the JSON in your controller (or in your service layer) and pass it to the view as an object (Model).

Comment: You can deserialize the JSON response to a class which can then be used same as your view is coded now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would agree with many of the previous comments, if you're using ASP.NET MVC you might as well do the JSON conversion from there (have a look at [JsonResult](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.jsonresult.aspx) class).  However, if you really want the WCF service to return the result in JSON format, [this](http://iainjmitchell.com/blog/?p=97) blog post I wrote a while back might help.

Iain